# compareTo() giving conflicting results in a client/server application?

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements, compareto

Hello everyone: I'm having a very weird issue with a simple multithreaded server/client app. I currently have two running hosts which runs say, Client 1 and Server 1, and another which runs C2 and S2. C1 sends a message to S2, who then shares it with C2. I then do different things based on what data (a string) was sent.

However, some of my comparisons give *conflicting* results. For example (`own_msg` refers to the String that the host client itself sends, `chat_msg` refers to the one that it receives via its server from the other client):

```
if(own_msg.compareTo("Let's play!") == 0 || own_msg.compareTo("Bye!") == 0) 
{
    break;
}
```

This works whenever the host client itself indeed chooses those options.

However, this does not:

```
if( !( chat_msg.compareTo("Bye!") == 0 || chat_msg.compareTo("Let's play!") == 0 ))
```

This is, for some reason, always true. Even when I print the contents of chat_msg to screen (from both the server *and* the client receiving the `chat_msg`), and know for **certain** that the outcome of that statement should be false. For example, `chat_msg = "Let's play!"` **does** go into the aforementioned if-statement.

Just what in the world is going on here? I'm currently testing this application on localhost, using different port pairs, so there should be no possibility of malformed packets (and even if there were, it wouldn't return the exact same string!). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I see some people are misconstruing my intention. As @RanEldan has stated as a comment to the answer below, I intend to go into the if statement if `chat_msg` is different from either "Bye!" or "Let's play!".

Note that inverting the if, i.e.:

```
if(chat_msg.compareTo("Bye!") == 0 || chat_msg.compareTo("Let's play!") == 0)
```

Causes the statement to *never* be entered. Therefore, I am inclined to believe @dasblinkenlight that there must be an invisible character. However, I am unsure as to how I to find out what it is, as the server string is passed directly into the shared variable.

Note that equals() has the exact same effect, and that the NetBeans debugger lists the Strings with no additional whitespace (i.e. `"Let's play!"`).

**EDIT 2**:

@SajalDutta's suggestion was indeed right! Since I'm using UDP together with a byte array, it seems that the 'length' of my strings is fixed at 1024, most likely padded with \0 or some such.

**Final edit**:

It seems that I was using the wrong String constructor to get the String from the Datagram. I was using `String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());`, instead of `String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());`

@SajalDutta, if you wish to post an answer to this consisting of the above, I would accept it since it led me to the correct answer. If not, I'll accept the closest one once some time has passed.

Comment: There must be an invisible character there somewhere in the server string.

Comment: Your statement will be true only if the value of chat_msg is not Bye! and is not Let's play!. Also mind the casing of the value of chat_msg.

Comment: Why are you useing compareTo to check if it is equal? why not .equals ?

Comment: Seriously, There's nothing wrong with your code as posted here. If `chat_msg` is one of those two strings (exactly, including case since you're not using `equalsIgnoreCase()`), it *will not* enter the `if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of the strings for some non-printable characters. :)

Comment: Note to self: Double-check the damn constructors! =P

Answer (score 1):

First, sometimes simple re-arrangement of logical expressions can improve code readability. For example, second condition is equal to the following (which looks more simple for me):

```
( chat_msg.compareTo("Bye!") != 0 && chat_msg.compareTo("Let's play!") != 0 )
```

Second, probably your client-server communication protocol adds some white space character to your string (and this character is not visible when you print the string). Try using debugger to check actual value of `chat_msg`.

Comment: Or by getting the length of chat_msg if debugger is not available.

Comment: @Ran - You mean other non-printable characters? At least length will give you a hint if it's Bye! or Bye!Some_other_unicode_char

Comment: Another option (if debugger is not available) would be, print all string character codes one-by-one :)